# Why is this boolean selection not counting NULLs?

Tags: hive, apache-spark

I have the table `my_table` containing a `boolean` column `my_value`. I receiving a somewhat surprising result when I query the table in Shark:

```
shark> SELECT my_value, COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY my_value;
OK
true    182285
false   81968
NULL    7594
Time taken: 14.028 seconds
shark> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE my_value=true;
OK
182285
Time taken: 13.787 seconds
shark> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE my_value IS NULL;
OK
7594
Time taken: 13.387 seconds
shark> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE my_value=true or my_value IS NULL;
OK
182285
Time taken: 13.406 seconds
```

**I expect the last query to return `189879` (that is, 182285+7594). Why isn't it?**

For the curious reader, this seems to yield the right result:

```
shark> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE isnull(my_value) or my_value=true;
OK
189879
```

Also, this is not an operator priority issue:

```
shark> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE (my_value=true) or (my_value IS NULL);
OK
182285
```

**Update:** Looks like the `IS` operator in the `WHERE` clause is not doing what I am expecting:

```
shark> SELECT my_value IS NULL FROM my_table WHERE my_value IS NULL LIMIT 10;
14/11/26 11:34:52 WARN parse.ASTRewriteUtil: Query contains a LIMIT. Skipping applicable COUNT DISTINCT rewrites.A LIMIT shouldn't be paired with an aggregation that only returns one line ...
OK
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

This makes me even more surprised that `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE my_value IS NULL;` returned a correct result.

Comment: Instead of using ``IS NULL``, what does ``SELECT COUNT(1) - COUNT(my_value) FROM my_table;`` return?

Comment: Sure, it outputs `7594`.

Comment: Seems like in your case NULL IS NULL evaluates to false? That is not how it is defined... Would explain though why the NULL values are excluded in the OR statement.